# Citilink airline ticket cancellation and refund

Tags: bookings, airlines, garuda

Last month I booked a flights with [Citilink](https://www.citilink.co.id/en) from Melbourne to Bali return for May. Last week i received a whatsapp message from Citilink saying the flights were cancelled until December. The whatsapp profile showed a bluetick mark. Then the next day I received an email saying flights were cancelled and you can email for a refund. So I emailed them for a refund and they sent me a form, the form asks for credit card number and expiry.
But when I log into the manage your flight on their portal, it does not show any cancelled status , it just says confirmed.

**Question:**

- How safe is it to provide this credit card info ?
- Is this the standard way they process a refund ?

Comment: Doesn't sound legit to me. You should call them.

Comment: @MichaelHampton apparently is it legit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Answering my own question might help others*]

Timeline:

**5 Mar 2020** - Got cancellation email from them

**5 Mar 2020** - Emailed refund@citilink.co.id for a refund

**7 Mar 2020** - Called up Citilink Aus number, they said I have to email for refund

**9 Mar 2020** - Got a reply from them asking to fill a form

**16 Mar 2020** - I submitted the froms but I left out certain stuff that I thought was too confidential

**20 Mar 2020** - No reply received, so sent a follow up email.

**27 Mar 2020** - Still No reply received, so sent another follow up email.

**2 Apr 2020** - They sent a new email saying some documents were missing

**10 Apr 2020** - I submitted missing documents

**20 Apr 2020** - No reply received, so sent a follow up email again (sigh).

**24 Apr 2020** - Received this email from them: "Refund Mr/Mrs have entered the queue to be processed by our acquiring bank. The refund process is depending on issuer bank. Please wait to receive the fund to the credit card."

**12 May 2020** - Still not received refund, sent another email asking for status.

**15 May 2020** - Checked bank account money finally received. Lost about AUD $40 due to currency conversion.

---

All is all took about 2 months .. including some delays caused by me.
They have a very bad process for refunds and very bad customer service.

Comment: I just got a refund from British Airways, no follow-up mails, took 3 full months. (And due to flight date, I was early in the queue.) Airlines do struggle these days.

Answer (score 3):

I am in the same boat as you.

I sent them all documents as requested - blurred out all sensitive information. Unfortunately this is typical Indonesia bureaucracy. They confirmed refund was being processed on Mar 10th but still nothing.

I strongly advise calling them and demanding a refund confirmation number or any type of documentation, as they have refused to provide this in writing since the very start.

I have also submitted a dispute via my credit card provider, not sure if that will help but I don't trust Citilink at all. Understand it's a horrifying time for the aviation industry but we need this money back more than ever now.

Good luck!

Comment: yes and they take 1 week to reply now

Comment: I don't think I can file a credit card dispute since its more than 30 days now

Answer (score 2):

Same boat.
We had flights booked, ended up getting an email saying they cancelled the service and asked for information to get a refund.

They asked for identification and a bank statement OR a scan of my debit card. I felt as though this kicks the door wide open for fraud so I tried to get into contact with someone from Citilink. The Australian contact number (which was very difficult to find) told me not to send a bank statement or scan of my debit card - this was apparently unnecessary and they weren't sure why the Indonesian team has asked people for this information.

The confirmation email (if you could call it that?) said for debit/credit card payments, the refund would take up to 30 days. It has now been 31 days, so I called them up today doing my best not to become abusive; the woman that answered said the only contact they have with the team in Jakarta overseeing the refunds is through email, and they hadn't replied to any emails for a while.

This company is an absolute joke. I don't know if you're still chasing your refund, but I'll post the Australian contact information below;

**EMAIL:** Citilink@aviationonline.com.au

**PHONE:** +61 86 5557081

Good luck.